# How do I reorganize exported validation functions in app.module.ts?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I'm new to Angular development and am stuck trying to figure out how to move validation functions out of app.module.ts into a validations module.

This works when placed in app.module.ts:

```
export function DateValidator(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors {
  if (!control.value) return null;
  let value = control.value instanceof Date ? control.value : Date.parse(control.value);
  return value instanceof Date ? null : { 'invalid': true };
}
```

But I want to move all of my validators into a feature module. When I try to do that, I get the following error message:

`ERROR in src/app/validators/validators.module.ts(6,22): error TS2322: Type '(control: FormControl) => ValidationErrors' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'.`

Here is what I'm trying to do:

validators/date.validator.ts:

```
import { FormControl, ValidationErrors } from "@angular/forms";

export function DateValidator(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors {
    if (!control.value) return null;
    let value = control.value instanceof Date ? control.value : Date.parse(control.value);
    return value instanceof Date ? null : { 'invalid': true };
}
```

And the validators/validators.module.ts file looks like this. I know this isn't correct but I'm not clear on when I need to import vs declare and when to export or provide. The documentation unfortunately doesn't clear any of this up for me.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DateValidator } from './date.validator';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DateValidator
  ]
})
export class ValidatorsModule { }
```

Comment: DateValidator is not an Angular NgModule. Importing it in another NgModule doesn't make sense. Validators are just pure functions, which don't need to be declared, imported, provided or anything Angular-related. You can put them in any file you want, and use them where you need them.

Comment: That’s not helpful. As I’ve said, I’m trying to get this working. How do I make a validator globally available?

Comment: You define it in any file you want and export it. And you import it wherever you need to use it. It's just a TypeScript function. You don't need to reference it in any NgModule.

Comment: The validators are being used in ngx-formly. So they need to be public functions. I believe an import makes the function privately available where imported.